# PHP + MySQL: How to auto login after registration

Tags: php, mysql

So what I want to accomplish is that users that registers get logged inn automatically but all i get is a white page and nothing happens... the data is added to the database but the user is not automatically logged in... Here's some code for you

First the form: (if there already is a user logged inn this will not show)

```
function registrer(){
if(!isset($_SESSION['brukerID'])){
echo'<center><h4>Registrer ny bruker!</h4></center><hr/>
<form method="POST" action="nybruker.php">
Passord<br>
    <input type="password" name="nybrukerpass" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Æ]).{8,}" title="Må bestå av minst 1 tall og en stor bokstav og små bokstaver og minst 8 bokstaver."><br>
Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="nybrukeremail" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="Epost@Domene.no"><br>
Fornavn<br>
    <input type="text" name="nybrukerfornavn" required ><br>
Etternavn<br>
    <input type="text" name="nybrukeretternavn" required ><br>
Adresse<br>
    <input type="text" name="nybrukeradresse" required ><br>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrer Nå!" name="sendKnapp">
    </p>
</form>';}
}
```

Now the nybruker.php:

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

$nybrukerpass = $_POST['nybrukerpass'];
$nybrukerfornavn = $_POST['nybrukerfornavn'];
$nybrukeretternavn = $_POST['nybrukeretternavn'];
$nybrukeradresse = $_POST['nybrukeradresse'];
$nybrukeremail = $_POST['nybrukeremail'];

 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Bruker (BrukerID, Passord, Fornavn, Etternavn, Adresse, Epost, ErAnsatt)
        VALUES('NULL','$nybrukerpass', '$nybrukerfornavn', '$nybrukeretternavn','$nybrukeradresse', '$nybrukeremail', '0')";

 $sql2 = "SELECT BrukerID FROM Bruker WHERE Fornavn = '$nybrukerfornavn' AND Etternavn = '$nybrukeretternavn')";

 $brukerid = $sql2;

if ($sql1 and $sql2) {
    mysql_query("COMMIT");
    $_SESSION['brukerID'] = $brukerid;
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
} else {        
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");    
    echo "feil i kode";
}
```

Comment: White page *(a.k.a. white screen of death)*: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Make sure you've started the session also, in all pages using sessions.

Comment: Plus, are you calling the `registrer()` function?

Comment: you probably shouldn't post your database credentials like that

Comment: You're open to SQL Injection, too. Always add `exit;` after sending a `header()` to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a session variable, but I don't see you starting a session in your script. Which would cause the problem you're describing where the user doesn't seem to be logged in. Add this to the top of your scripts if it's not already there.

```
session_start();
```

Comment: `but all i get is a white page` - is the problem which won't be caused by not having `session_start()`. There is most likely a syntax error in the rest of OPs code *somewhere*.

Comment: If there was a syntax error, your record wouldn't be inserted into the database. I assume what's happening is you're not setting the session variable correctly, then redirecting to index.php. Index.php sees that the session is not set and redirects somewhere else, or causes a redirect loop, etc.

Comment: If there was a redirect loop, then the browser would quit and show there is (at least in Chrome it does) - anyway, there isn't enough information provided by OP to fully determine. *However*, a white-screen-of-death is usually an Internal Server Error - which is usually caused by a syntax error.

Comment: If it were a syntax error, the data would never be added to the database, right? The OP explains the data _does_ get added.